# C# WebBrowser Control Issue

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Hello i am new in this and i am making a tool to auto make netflix account but i need to know all the 
WebBrowser Control i only know this

```
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = textBox2.Text;
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("regFormButton").InvokeMember("Click");
```

And i need to know to click on a Agreement Checkbox i can use this

> webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("agree_box").InvokeMember("Click");

and some thinks dont have a ID only classes and values WHAT CAN I DO ?

Answer (score 0):

You might use GetElementsByTagName then iterate them